# Ticket logging portal for Azure DevOps

Tags: portal, ticket-system

I would like to create a ticket logging page for key-users to log tickets to Azure DevOps.
Is this possible and how? I hope to be finding a standard option I can select like in Jira for instance.

Comment: hey, did find anything about this question? is there a way?